# Right method of accessing properties of objects inside other objects in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ipad, class-variables

I have a Singleton Class SharedDataObject which has a another class object myClass. MyClass has BOOL variables as well. I provided accessors (nonatomic,retain) for MyClass and (assign, readwrite) to myClass Instance variables. I have also synthesized each one of them. But when I access them to read value or write value with

```
[[SharedDataObject getInstance].myClass available];
```

OR

```
[[SharedDataObject getInstance].myClass setAvailable:YES];
```

It gives me following warning:

```
 no 'available:' method found
 no 'setAvailable' method found
```

But I can read and write values to it. I want to remove warnings. What am I doing wrong? Or if it is a wrong way to access it?

Class Declarations are:

```
@interface SharedDataObject : NSObject {
    MyClass *myClass;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) MyClass *myClass;

+ (SharedDataObject*) getInstance;

@end


@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    BOOL available;
}
@property (assign, readwrite) BOOL available;

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:

1. Include the .h for `MyClass`
2. <s>The singleton's myClass property returns `MyClass*`, not some base-class</s> (answered in update to question)

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you do

```
[SharedDataObject getInstance].myClass.available
```

Comment: It gives same warning. Nothing different.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you well, your myClass is a class property of your SharedDataObject class, so you cannot access it as it was a instance property.

Can you provide us with the full declaration of the classes?

Does

```
[[SharedDataObject myClass] available]
```

works?

Comment: I have appended class declarations. I think you mean [[[SharedDataObject getInstance] myClass] available]? Yes, it also gives the same warning.

Comment: I thought your "myClass" was also a class property nor a instance property :)